# How do You specify javaType in Mybatis for an int[] type of postgres database?

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

eg：
UserMapper.xml

```xml
    <resultMap id="baseResultMap" type="com.xxx.UserDO">
        <result column="id" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER"></result>
        <result column="groups" property="groups" jdbcType="??????"></result>
        <result column="name" property="name" jdbcType="VARCHAR"></result>
    </resultMap>
```

UserDO.java

```java
public class UserDO {
    private Long id;
    private ?????? groups;
    private String name;
}
```

User table ddl:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."users" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
  "name" varchar(320) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" NOT NULL,
  "groups" int4[],
)
```

The value stored in the database is：

[image]

```
{1,2}
```

I want to define the jdbcType of the Groups field in the XML file for UserMapper！！！

please help me ！！！

Comment: That would be `jdbcType=ARRAY`, but it would not do anything good by itself. Assuming that the type of `UserDO.groups` is `Integer[]`, you should specify `typeHandler` instead i.e. `<result column="groups" property="groups" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler" />`.

Comment: Got it。so I'm going to make an Array converter that inherits BaseTypeHandler, right?

Comment: There is a built-in `ArrayTypeHandler`, so the `<result />` in my previous comment should work as-is.

Comment: ok,got it,thanks for your help